# jQuery mouseleave на смартфонах

Tags: jquery

Имеется меню, с выпадающими подменю:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.paragraph').each(function() {
        $(this).on('mouseenter', function() {
            $(this).find('.submenu').fadeIn(150);
        });
        $(this).on('mouseleave', function() {
            $(this).find('.submenu').fadeOut(150);
        });
    });
});
```

Проблема в том, что событие mouseleave на мобильных устройвах не работает. При таче в другое место экрана меню не пропадает. Баг был решен добавлением события  touchstart на body:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.paragraph').each(function() {
        $(this).on('mouseenter', function() {
            $(this).find('.submenu').fadeIn(150);
        });
        $(this).on('mouseleave', function() {
            $(this).find('.submenu').fadeOut(150);
        });
        $('body').on('touchstart', function() {
            $(this).find('.submenu').fadeOut(150);
        });
    });
});
```

Все работает. Тап по ссылке один раз дает открытие всплывающего меню, тап два раза - переходит по ссылке.

Теперь другая проблема. Если тапнуть один раз на кнопку меню, потом в другое место экрана, чтобы это меню закрыть, а потом снова на это меню, то вместо выпадания подменю, ссылка сразу же открывается. А нужно, чтобы снова открывалось подменю. Я так понимаю что, когда первый раз тапаешь на меню, он запоминает, что на него уже 1 раз нажали, и когда я жму второй раз - сразу переходит по ссылке. Можно как-то сбросить этот счетчик? Или по-другому сделать, чтобы меню открывалось и на 2, 3, 4... разы?